# Is there a way to combine view functions of similar structures into one? Django

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner at Django. Recently, I started writing a web app for inventory management and I realised that when i was writing the views, there were a lot of them with similar structures. For instance:

```
def invoices(request):
    """The page for displaying invoices."""
    invoice_list = Document.objects.filter(type_name__name='Invoice')
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(invoice_list, 10)

    try:
        invoices = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        invoices = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        invoices = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'invoices':invoices}
    return render(request, 'imsapp/invoices.html', context)
```

and this one:

```
def credit_notes(request):
    """The page for displaying credit notes."""
    credit_notes_list = Document.objects.filter(type_name__name='Credit Note')
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(credit_notes_list, 10)

    try:
        credit_notes = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        credit_notes = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        credit_notes = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'credit_notes':credit_notes}
    return render(request, 'imsapp/credit_notes.html', context)
```

So, I'm just thinking if there is a more elegant way to represent the above function definitions. Is Class-based view what I'm looking for?

Comment: CBV is the best option in these situations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refactor the logic such that a function handles the common logic or you can use a class based view.

```
def paginate(request, queryset):
    page_index = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(queryset, 10)

    try:
        page = paginator.page(page_index)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return page

def credit_notes(request):
    """The page for displaying credit notes."""
    credit_notes_list = Document.objects.filter(type_name__name='Credit Note')
    credit_notes = paginate(request, credit_notes_list)
    context = {'credit_notes':credit_notes}
    return render(request, 'imsapp/credit_notes.html', context)
```

Or you can use ListView

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
class CreditNoteListView(ListView):
    queryset = Document.objects.filter(type_name__name='Credit Note')
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'imsapp/credit_notes.html'
```

You'll need to change your template in that case though since the template context will be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Views are just Python functions - and as such, tehy can call further functions.

In the above code, it looks like the only things that change are the type object name and the template.

Simply create a new function that takes these two as parameters

```py
def paged_view(request, type_name, template, name_in_context):
    """The page for displaying various items in a paginated way."""
    item_list = Document.objects.filter(type_name__name=time_name)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(item_list, 10)

    try:
        items = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        items = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {name_in_context:items}
    return render(request, template, context)

def invoices(request):
    """The page for displaying invoices."""
    return paged_view(requests, 'imsapp/invoices.html', 'Invoice', 'invoices')

def credit_notes(request):
    """The page for displaying credit notes."""
    return paged_view(requests, 'imsapp/credit_notes.html', 'Credit Note', 'credit_notes')
```